# RESTfull Service is not accepting object as parameter

Tags: wcf, rest

```
[WebInvoke(Method="POST",UriTemplate="/Users",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string StudentUsers(Student user)
{
    return string.Format("Hello {0}", user.Name);
}
```

Above code is my REST service. And my client code is :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Student user = 
    new Stuent {
        Name="Test User", 
        Email = "test@test.com",    
        Password = "test" 
    };                
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(user.GetType());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ser.WriteObject(ms, user);
String json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(json);
writer.Close();

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

My service is hosted and I'm using webHttpBinding. When I debug my REST service I'm receiving `null` in Student object. I am sure that my post method is sending data as I test it by taking Name, Email and Password as parameters at REST service so my data is posted successfully but the thing is my Json data which is posted is not getting converted to Student object. I read somewhere that RESTfull Service will convert that Json data to object. Is that true or we need to convert it explicitly?

Comment: can you use fiddler to determine the server gets the POST-ed data?. What is the return value from your request? is it 400, 500, 200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by changing WebInvoke to

```
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST",UriTemplate="/Users",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sent the Content-Length for your POST-ed data:

```
request.ContentLength = ms.Length;
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) for more details:

Comment: thanks to the answers. I have used request.ContentLength=ms.Length also. My problem is my post method is sending the student object as json data like "{"Name":"myname","Email":"myemail","Password":"mypassword"}". And at server side the service method is not converting json request to student object instead it is converting json request into 3 different parameters as Name,Email and Password. What I want is that json data is to be converted back to my student object so that i can use that object directly.

Comment: sorry for the delay answer but I got the answer. It was simple, by just changing BodyStyle attribute to Bare [WebInvoke(Method="POST",UriTemplate="/Users",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)].